# AppleScript - If file is listed in excel sheet add another column value as prefix

Tags: excel, macos, applescript, rename, automator

FACTS:

- I have a folder that contains a bunch of .pdf files. Names look like (2-581.pdf, 131-681.pdf, 1138-4.pdf, ...)
- The .pdf files are broken into two parts partA-partB.pdf seperated by "-"
- I have an excel sheet that lists all the results in the folder
- The Excel sheet has many pdfs listed in it, more than are in the folder.
- The Excel sheet first 2 rows are title and headers
- The Excel sheet first column is the test# which would be the prefix
- The Excel sheet 4th column is partA of the original .pdf filename, 5th column partB

Ideal outcome-
I run the automator / applescript and point it to the folder containing the .pdfs and the excel sheet containing the information. It runs and renames all the .pdfs in the folder that are found in the excel. The renamed files would consist of the test#, a space, and the original name. The row in the excel sheet would be highlighted / flagged in some way, showing it was found.

I have searched a few different forums as well as this one and have tried to piece together code to try and get something to work. I won't paste this code as I haven't gotten any of it to work in my scenario.

The following code I merged copied from another help forum and tried to tweak it for my scenario. It sort of works for the first 6 items then just stops (I think because the 7th item is not in the folder). Also, to get it to work I had to manually create the original file names and new files names within the excel. I did this because I wasn't able to get it to work outside of excel.

Any and all help, suggestions, links to possible solutions are welcome. I have A LOT of test results to go through on many different excel sheets and this would save me a ton of time. I lost today trying to figure this out myself. I am either overthinking this or in over my head. Thank you!

```
set KeyFileName to choose file with prompt "Choose the Excel file"
set WorkingDirectory to (choose folder with prompt "Please locate the folder  with the processed .pdf's.") as string
set KeyFilePath to WorkingDirectory & KeyFileName
set FileNamesKey to my GetFileNamesKey(KeyFilePath)
set theResult to ChangeFileNames(WorkingDirectory, FileNamesKey)
return theResult
end run

to GetFileNamesKey(KeyFilePath)
    tell application "Microsoft Excel"

    set ResultsRange to used range of active sheet of active workbook

    set FileNames to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to count of rows in ResultsRange
        set NewFileName to value of third column of row i of ResultsRange
        set OldFileName to value of second column of row i of ResultsRange
        set FileNames to FileNames & {{OldFileName, NewFileName}}

    end repeat

    return FileNames

end tell
end GetFileNamesKey

to ChangeFileNames(WorkingDirectory, FileNamesKey)

tell application "Finder"
    repeat with aFile in FileNamesKey
        set OldFileName to item 1 of aFile
        set NewFileName to item 2 of aFile



        set PathToFile to WorkingDirectory & OldFileName
        try
            set FileExtension to name extension of file (WorkingDirectory & (item 1 of aFile))
            set name of file PathToFile to NewFileName & "." & FileExtension
        on error
            exit repeat
            return false
        end try
    end repeat
end tell

return true
end ChangeFileNames
return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I well understand, you have an excel file with col.A= #test, col.B= oldFileName (xx-yyy.pdf), col.C= NewName (empty?), Col.D= PartA (xx), Col.E= PartB (yyy)

You want to loop through all rows of that file, search if file from Col.B exists in a selected folder and if so, you want to change file's name (=colA + " " + old name) and make it visible in Excel row.

If OK, then script below does what you want. In case file is found in selected folder, I marked the Excel row in 2 ways: set new file name in column C (not sure if it was empty before ?) and I set its color to red. I added many comments to make it clear (I hope !) :

```
set KeyFileName to choose file with prompt "Choose the Excel file"
set WorkingDirectory to (choose folder with prompt "Please locate the folder  with the processed .pdf's.") as string

tell application "Microsoft Excel"
open KeyFileName
set ResultsRange to used range of active sheet of active workbook
-- Data bloc starts row 2 with headers and then row 3 to x
-- col.A= #test, col.B= oldFileName (xx-yyy.pdf), col.C= NewName (empty), Col.D= PartA (xx), Col.E= PartB (yyy)
repeat with i from 2 to count of rows in ResultsRange
    -- loop through each Excel row only starting row 2 of the range to skip hearders
    set OldFileName to value of second column of row i of ResultsRange
    set NewName to (value of the first column of row i of ResultsRange) & " " & OldFileName
    set theFile to WorkingDirectory & OldFileName
    tell application "Finder" to set FileExist to (file theFile exists) --check file exists
    if FileExist then
        tell application "Finder" to set name of file theFile to NewName --change file name in the folder
        set (value of third column of row i of ResultsRange) to NewName -- set new name in Excel col.C
        set (color index of interior object of third column of row i of ResultsRange) to 3 -- = Red !
    end if
end repeat --- next Excel row
end tell
```

The line "Open KeyFileName" can be skipped is Excel file is already open. Also the script does not save the Excel file after the changes !

Comment: I ran this and it comes back with an error that states:

Finder got an error: Can't make {1.0, " ", "A-53.pdf"} into type Unicode text.

The highlighted code that comes with this error is the following:

`if FileExist then
   tell application "Finder" **to set name of file theFile to NewName**`

Comment: Strange I tested it OK on my side. I think it may come from value of your column A. First add a line just before the "if FileExist.." with : log "name=" & NewName. it will show the value of NewName. based on your error, it seems it becomes a list instead of a string. if so, then you may have to change the line "set NewName...". check first and let me know, I'll update script.

Comment: I tried adding the log line you mentioned above and I got the same error. Not really sure how to check the logs to see what that variable was pulling.

I was able to add "as text" after set OldName and NewName and that worked. the script now runs, I see the cells turn red and the files rename!

renamed files are named with the number prefix with a decimal place. I removed the decimal spaces in the excel sheet in the formatting but it seems to still put it there in the name.

EXAMPLE: "75.0 769-315.pdf"

Comment: it looks to be the value of your test# prefix. Of course it should only be made of characters authorized in a file name. Personally, I avoid anything like - , ; / : = . + ... Yes, the dot is allowed but I prefer to reserve it for file extension. you may have to change your prefix in Excel. if always a number, you can coerce it to an integer in the script (as integer instead of as text).